# PowerBI multiple foreign key columns

Tags: foreign-keys, powerbi, data-warehouse, relation, azure-synapse

I have the a table structure similar to this simplified example in my Data Warehouse:

Table "Records":

- ID
- Date
- Car
- Truck

Table "Vehicles":

- ID
- VehicleType
- LicensePlate

Now I want to visualize the data with PowerBI. The problem occurs when I try to add relations. Because from the "Records" table both the "Car" and "Truck" columns are foreign keys referencing the "Vehicles" table, PowerBI throws the following error:

> You cannot create a direct active relationship between x and y because there is already an active set of indirect relationships between these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two separate tables in your model, `VehiclesCars` and `VehiclesTrucks`. Filter them on `VehicleType` to contain only the relevant rows.

[image]

Or if you want to have a list with all vehicles, create a computed column in `Records` table like this:

```
VehicleId = IF(ISBLANK(Records[Car]); Records[Truck]; Records[Car])
```

And create only one foreign key between `Records` and `Vehicles`:

[image]